# Directory Services Created objects not showing in Active Directory Remote Management Tools

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am creating a test user/group using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory. I can fetch the user/group successfully when using the c#. However when I refresh Active Directory Remote Management Tools the test user/group don't show up.

I know that the objects are there because when I try to create the same object in Active Directory Remote Management Tools it says I can't create it because it already exists. After that It magically appears in the window.

**Test User**

```
var user =  Root.Children.Add("CN=TestUser", "user");
using (user)
{
    user.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = "TestUser";
    user.CommitChanges();
}
```

**Test Group**

```
var group = Root.Children.Add("CN=TestGroup", "group");
using (group)
{
    group.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value = "TestGroup";
    group.CommitChanges();
}
```

Is there a reason why I can't see the test user/group created in code until I try to add them with Active Directory Remote Management Tools?

Comment: Are there multiple DC in the picture? This may happen if sync between the DC where the user was actually created, and the DC to which RSAT tool is connected are different.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Yes there are multiple dc. But I specify the one I connection when I open the ldap connection. Is there a way to force a quick sync? Also how so c# show the correct changes but Active Directory Remote Management Tools does not when they are connected to the same dc?

Comment: Have you checked this by logging in on the DC itself? I believe the refresh in the RSAT client for desktop PCs is somewhat ineffective in terms of refresh. You will have a better picture on the Domain Controller itself, which should show you the live object. If you really want to see the refreshed view using the RSAT tool, then I think clicking on some other OU/container than the one where the object is created, next followed by navigating back to the container/OU where the object is created would show you the newly created object.